# Yitzchak Avinu and Eretz Yisrael

Tags: marriage, eretz-yisrael, avot-patriarch-fathers, shidduchim-dating, parashat-chaye-sara

I remember reading somewhere that the reason Yitzchak did not go to see Rivkah before engaging/marrying her (even though you are supposed to see the girl before engaging/marrying her per gemara kiddushin 41) was because he was not "supposed" to leave Eretz Yisrael.

1- Is there a source for this?
2- Why was Yitzchak not "supposed" to leave Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: IIRC it's because he was הוקדש (sanctified) as a קרבן (offering) by the *Akeidah*, but I don't recall where I heard that. If I find a source for that I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Shokhet I believe Rashi cites it in this week's parsha when Yitzchok thought to go to Gerar.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48194/759

Answer (score 7):

[Rashi on Breishit 26:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=327) (@Yez is correct).

Summarizing Rashi and Sifsei Chachamim's emmendations - Yitzhak was considered as a sacrifice (which, he was from the akieda). Sifsei Chachamim says he was considered *Kodesh Kadashim* ("most holy") and such sacrifices were not allowd to be taken out of the azarah. The entire land of Israel was considered the *azara* at that time.

I'm uncertain how Sifsei Chachamim makes the claim in the last sentence.

Comment: Possibly relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48435/who-did-the-avos-give-maaser-to#comment128117_48435